# kaminaris url generated is not relative url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I pust a kaminari url in controller `facilator` , action `index`

I put viewer helper in as `<%= paginate @sessions %>`

but the link it generated is `http://localhost:3000/?page=2`
the link i want would be `http://localhost:3000/facilator/index?page=2`

How should i get it to work? I tried to add controller and action as params after paginate. but it didn't work. it will always return to the root url instead of current url.

## Update:

In this page, it is not CRUD. It is one of my customized page.

My routes file: `get 'facilator/index'`

Controller File: `@sessions = QSession.where(:user_id=>current_user.id).page params[:page]`

Comment: What about editing your `routes.rb` as `get 'facilator/sessions', to: 'facilators#index'`?

Comment: That won't work. Also, facilitator/index is not about sessions. (Sessions model is not under facilitator.)

Comment: Add more info., that's not enough.

Comment: i just updated with more information. Could you let me know if i need anything else? Thank you so much.